# Expecting several lines of output, why am I getting only one line?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, intervals, break

Why does my class interval output only one when I enter 10 or more data? I use while loop here. What's missing?

```
num= min;
while (num <=max){

    cout<< "class interval"<< endl;
    cout << num <<setw(5)<<"      ";
    cout<< (num-1)+ interval<< setw(6);
    

    if (num=max)

        break;
```

I want to have the class interval that I enter from class size to show like

```
50-60
60-70
70-80
```

But when I run it the only show is
`50-60` and the program ended.

Comment: In `if (num=max)` remember what is the difference between `==` and `= `. And please make clear which programming language you are asking about, or the people knowing about that language likely will not notice your question.

Comment: [what is the difference between == and =](https://cplusplus.com/forum/general/18183/)